# How do I fix Needs["OpenCLLink`"] failure?

Tags: parallelization, gpu

In Mathematica 8.0.4 under Mac OS X 10.8.2, when I evaluate

```
Needs["OpenCLLink`"]
```

I get error `General::cdir: Cannot set current directory to authserver.`

Where should that directory be?

Comment: First: it works for me (MMA 8.0.4.0 on 10.8.2, recent MacBook Pro). Second: I had the same problem with CUDALink some time ago, and it actually happened as a byproduct of CUDA actually not being supported on my hardware. And, the error was non fatal, i.e. the CUDALink package was actually loaded even though I had the error. So, I suppose my advise is two-fold:  1. Are you sure it matters?  2. After you run this command, what is the output of `OpenCLGQ[]`?

Comment: The result of `OpenCLQ[]` (not `OpenCLGQ[]`) is `True`. And, in fact, OpenCL does seem to be working. Guess I'll report the possibly spurious error message to Wolfram tech support. Thanks, @F'x.

Answer (score 1):

Current status on this is that the error can be seen somewhat randomly on OpenCLLink and CUDALink packages on Mac OS MMA 8.0.4.0. The package appears to be correctly loaded despite the error.